# Fetching data with pdo and displaying with ajax in oop php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, oop

Something thats been bothering me for a while.I was learning to make a log in system using oop php, ajax and bootstrap using pdo.

So far I have got the log in and sign up part right.
User enters info in form, gets submitted to auth.php which runs its respective method in  user.php through an ajax file which looks like this

```
$(function(){

    $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);

        submitForm($form);
    });

});

function submitForm($form){

    $footer = $form.parent('.modal-body').next('.modal-footer');

    $footer.html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        method: $form.attr('method'),
        data : $form.serialize(),
        success : function( response ){
            response = $.parseJSON( response );

            if(response.success){
                if(!response.signout){
                    $footer.html( response.message );
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $footer.html( response.message );
                        window.location = response.url;
                    }, 1500
                    );
                } 
                else if(response.signout == 2){
                    $footer.html( response.message );
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#signup').modal('hide');
                        $('#login').modal('show');
                    }, 2000
                    );
                }
                else if(response.signout == 3){
                    $footer.html( response.idid );
                }   
            }
            else if(response.error){
                $footer.html( response.message );
            }
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
}
```

In case of log in, the ajax submits info to auth.php which runs the method in user.php and logs the user in

auth.php looks like this:

```
   <?php

require_once 'includes/init.php';

$status = $user->login($_POST, $db);

if($status === 'success'){
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => 'success', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-success">Authenticated successfully</p>',
        'url' => 'profile.php',
    ]);
}
else if($status === 'successAdmin'){
    echo json_encode([
        'success' => 'success', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-info">Welcome Admin</p>',
        'url' => 'profileAdmin.php',
    ]);
}
else if($status === 'missing_fields'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">All fields are mandatory</p>',
    ]);
}
else if($status === 'email_dosent_exist'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">The e-mail/phone number address you provided does not exist. Please create an account first.</p>',
    ]);
}

else if($status === 'error'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => 'error', 
        'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect e-mail/phone number or password</p>',
    ]);
}
```

after that it runs a method in user.php and sets the session varaibles

```
public function login($user, $db){

    if(empty($user['emailPhone']) OR empty($user['password'])){
        return 'missing_fields';
    }
    else if(!$this->emailExists($user['emailPhone'],$db) AND !$this->phoneExists($user['emailPhone'],$db)){
        return 'email_dosent_exist';
    }
    else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? OR `phone_number`=?" ;
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);



    if( is_object($statement) ){

        $statement->bindParam(1, $user['emailPhone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(2, $user['emailPhone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        if($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

            if(password_verify($user['password'], $row->password)){
                if ( $row->is_admin == 'admin') {
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = [
                        'id'    =>  $row->id,
                        'name'  =>  $row->name,
                        'c1'    =>  $row->course1,
                        'conf1' =>  $row->paid1,
                        'c2'    =>  $row->course2,
                        'conf2' =>  $row->paid2,
                        'c3'    =>  $row->course3,
                        'conf3' =>  $row->paid3,
                        'c4'    =>  $row->course4,
                        'conf4' =>  $row->paid4,
                        'c5'    =>  $row->course5,
                        'conf5' =>  $row->paid5,
                        'isBossMan' =>  $row->is_admin,
                    ];
                    return 'successAdmin';
                }

                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = [
                    'id'    =>  $row->id,
                    'name'  =>  $row->name,
                    'c1'    =>  $row->course1,
                    'conf1' =>  $row->paid1,
                    'c2'    =>  $row->course2,
                    'conf2' =>  $row->paid2,
                    'c3'    =>  $row->course3,
                    'conf3' =>  $row->paid3,
                    'c4'    =>  $row->course4,
                    'conf4' =>  $row->paid4,
                    'c5'    =>  $row->course5,
                    'conf5' =>  $row->paid5,
                ]; 


                return 'success';
            }



        }

    }
    }
    return 'error';
}
```

But I am using too many session variables. Is this a good practice ?

Also I need help to display data back at profile.php without using session variables. I want to run a sql statement in user.php to select all of current users data from table and display as a table in his profile.php page ?

So far what I have got is

```
public function displayInfo($user, $db){

    $sql = "SELECT `name`, `email`,`institute_name`, `country_code`, `phone_number`,  FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? OR `phone_number`=?" ;
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    if( is_object($statement) ){

        $statement->bindParam(1, $user['adminFetch'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(2, $user['adminFetch'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        if($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']['isBossMan'])) {
                return 'success';
                echo json_encode($row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about this ? I know that the row variable has the necessary information I want to display but how do I display that on profile.php page ?
Do i need to write another ajax code for displaying or the same one can be used to do it ?

A bit of progress that I made so far:
I have a field on profile.php page where user enters anyone`s email in and press a button to fetch info on that user from database fetches users info from table and displays in a div on profile.php with a new fetch ajax code I wrote for it:

```
function fetchForm($fetch){
    $fetchFooter = $fetch.parent('.modal-body').next('.modal-fetchFooter');
    $fetchFooter.html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">');
    $fetchBody = $fetchFooter.next();
    $.ajax({
        url: $fetch.attr('action'),
        method: $fetch.attr('method'),
        data : $fetch.serialize(),
        success : function( data ){
            data = $.parseJSON( data );
            $fetchFooter.html(data);

            if(data.error){
                $fetchFooter.html(data.message);
            }
        else{
            $fetchFooter.html(data);
        }       
     }
    })
}
```

which sends it to this fetch.php file which has the following code and runs a method in user.php to retrieve info

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/init.php';    
    $status = $user->displayInfo($_POST, $db);

    if( $status === 'missing_fields'){
        echo json_encode([
            'error'=> 'error', 
            'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a e-mail address or phone number to fetch data.</p>',

        ]);
    }
```

the user.php`s method looks like

```
public function displayInfo($user, $db){
        if(empty($user['adminFetch'])){
            return 'missing_fields';
        }

        else if(!$this->emailExists($user['adminFetch'],$db) AND !$this->phoneExists($user['adminFetch'],$db)){
            return 'emailphone_dosent_exist';
        }

        else{
            $sql = "SELECT `name`, `email`,`institute_name`, `country_code`, `phone_number` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=? OR `phone_number`=?" ;
            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
            if( is_object($statement) ){

                $statement->bindParam(1, $user['adminFetch'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->bindParam(2, $user['adminFetch'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $statement->execute();
                if($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']['isBossMan'])) {                      
                       echo json_encode($row);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 'missing_fields';    
    }
```

It is working fine in the case you dont enter anything and press the button. The div is replaced by error code.

But when the user types a correct existing email or phone number, the method and the fetch.php is returning 2 json objects.
One has the user info and the other has the error status.

What am I doing wrong, how do I make it so it only returns 1 json with info in true case or error json in false case ?

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you have `echo json_encode($row)` AFTER you return statement. That line of code will never be executed. If you remove the `return 'success';` line, you may be good to go. In answer to your question "is that too many session variables?" well, that depends. Since you have an inexpensive query you can run to get that data, I'd recommend just saving the logged-in user's id and running the query if you need the rest. Unless that means you run the query millions of times, which wouldn't be so great. So it depends a lot on how often you need to access that data.

Comment: I see but I am new to oop and ajax so I want to know if I need `json_encode` there in user.php file. Because the view.php file (which is similar to auth.php) is running this `displayInfo` method and already has a json_encode depending on what is returned from user.php just like the auth.php file. So do I need the `json_encode` there or is there a way to forward the `$row` to view.php and then display on profile.php page ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
All I had to do was return $row in user.php and encode $status in fetch.php like so

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/init.php';    
    $status = $user->displayInfo($_POST, $db);

    if( $status === 'missing_fields'){
        echo json_encode([
            'error'=> 'error', 
            'message'=> '<p class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a e-mail address or phone number to fetch data.</p>',

        ]);
    }
    else{echo json_encode($status)}
```

And then ajax was able to display the error and data just fine!